# How to call jq written in shell with python subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, jq

I have two following shell scripts.

**nodes.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

NODE_IDs=$(docker node ls --format "{{.ID}}")
for NODE_ID in ${NODE_IDs}
do
    docker node inspect $NODE_ID | jq -r '.[] | {node:.ID, ip:.Status.Addr}'
done | jq -s
```

*nodes.sh* gives following output (with `./nodes.sh` or `cat ./nodes.sh | bash`):

```
[
  {
    "node": "b2d9g6i9yp5uj5k25h1ehp26e",
    "ip": "192.168.1.123"
  },
  {
    "node": "iy25xmeln0ns7onzg4jaofiwo",
    "ip": "192.168.1.125"
  }
]
```

**node_detail.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker node inspect b2d | jq '.[] | {node: .ID, ip: .Status.Addr}'
```

where as *node_detail.sh* gives (`./node_detail.sh` or `cat ./node_detail.sh`):

```
{
  "node": "b2d9g6i9yp5uj5k25h1ehp26e",
  "ip": "192.168.1.123"
}
```

**Problem**: I would like to run both script from python `subporcess`.

I can run and get output for *node_detail.sh* with following code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('./node_detail.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> proc.stdout.read()
'{\n  "node": "b2d9g6i9yp5uj5k25h1ehp26e",\n  "ip": "192.168.1.123"\n}\n'
```

I wrote following code to get output from *nodes.sh*

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('./nodes.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
>>> jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

    jq is a tool for processing JSON inputs, applying the
    given filter to its JSON text inputs and producing the
    filter's results as JSON on standard output.
    The simplest filter is ., which is the identity filter,
    copying jq's input to its output unmodified (except for
    formatting).
    For more advanced filters see the jq(1) manpage ("man jq")
    and/or https://stedolan.github.io/jq

    Some of the options include:
     -c     compact instead of pretty-printed output;
     -n     use `null` as the single input value;
     -e     set the exit status code based on the output;
     -s     read (slurp) all inputs into an array; apply filter to it;
     -r     output raw strings, not JSON texts;
     -R     read raw strings, not JSON texts;
     -C     colorize JSON;
     -M     monochrome (don't colorize JSON);
     -S     sort keys of objects on output;
     --tab  use tabs for indentation;
     --arg a v  set variable $a to value <v>;
     --argjson a v  set variable $a to JSON value <v>;
     --slurpfile a f    set variable $a to an array of JSON texts read from <f>;
    See the manpage for more options.
Error: writing output failed: Broken pipe
Error: writing output failed: Broken pipe
```

Why I am getting *Error: writing output failed: Broken pipe*?

Comment: This seems so complex for such a simple task. Can't you use the Docker Python library directly?

Comment: @Paolo I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nodes.sh, rather than invoking jq without any argument, invoke it as `jq -s .`.